What is the quotient of the unit sphere by the bilateral shift on infinite-dimensional separable real Hilbert space?
Let H denote the real Hilbert space 2(ℤ) with its usual inner product.
If {en  |  n ∈ ℤ} denotes its standard orthonormal basis, define the unitary mapping W : H → H via W(en) = en+1, extended linearly to all of H.
Let S denote the unit sphere of H: S  =  {x ∈ H  |  ||x|| = 1}. Note that W(S) = S.
Then W|S generates an isometric action of the group ℤ on S that is free and properly discontinuous.
Question: What is the quotient S/W of S by W ?
Thoughts: Since S is contractible, S/W must be a K(ℤ,1).  This seems to make S/W into some Riemannian Hilbert manifold that is a fibre bundle over the circle. Is this correct? If so, what is its fibre? And what is its glueing map?

Two Hilbert manifolds are homotopy equivalent iff they are diffeomorphic, so the resulting space is just $S^{1} \times H$.

Yes. I'd like to know its Riemannian structure.
